# Configuring Spring security for authorized and non-authorized restful services

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security

I've a Spring Boot application providing secure Restful web services. It works well with following `HttpSecurity` configuration in it's own `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   http.csrf().disable();
   http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
   http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/secure/**").hasRole(ROLE_XXX)
      .anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
}
```

This configuration forces all webservices to be authorized under `/secure`. 
Now I want to add another a webservice, say `/public/test`, which can be called without any authentication. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Overriding `void configure(WebSecurity web)` method solved my problem:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
web.ignoring().antMatchers("/public/**");
}
```